# Repository Experiments with C# .NET and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

I'm building an asset tracking application. Using SQL server 2008, C# .NET, and Entity Framework. This is my first experience creating a repository, which according to my research is meant to abstract the data access process. I've been experimenting with a few designs, and I'm curious if any of them are good, or pose any severe development risks. The repository should support querying assets by serial number, barcode, or hostname.

For the purpose of keeping the examples short, I'm not including update, delete, insert methods. Also, the examples ignore possible generic implementations, as a generic implementation could always be worked out later, and right now would serve only to make the examples more confusing. Please read the following 3 designs and let me know if I'm on the right track with any of them:

### Design 1

My first design looked like this:

```
public interface IAssetRepository
{
    public Asset fetchBySerialNumber(String serialNumber);
    public Asset fetchByBarcode(String barcode);
    public ICollection<Asset> fetchByHostname(String hostname);
    public Asset fetchActiveByHostname(String hostname);
}

public class AssetRepository : IAssetRepository
{
    private InventoryEntites entities;

    public Asset fetchBySerialNumber(String serialNumber)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.SerialNumber == serialNumber
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public Asset fetchByBarcode(String barcode)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Barcode == barcode
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public Asset fetchActiveByHostname(String hostname)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Hostname == hostname && a.IsDeployed == true
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public ICollection<Asset> fetchByHostname(String hostname)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Hostname == hostname
                                  select a;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

### Design 2

In my second try I thought I could take advantage of ad-hoc polymorphism by wrapping the primitive types used as parameters:

```
public interface IAssetRepository
{
    public Asset fetch(SerialNumber serialNumber);
    public Asset fetch(Barcode barcode);
    public ICollection<Asset> fetch(Hostname hostname);
    public Asset fetchActive(Hostname hostname);
}

public class SerialNumber
{
    private String value;

    public SerialNumber(String value)
    { this.value = value; }

    public String Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}

// Barcode and Hostname classes are similar to SerialNumber

public class AssetRepository : IAssetRepository
{
    private InventoryEntites entities;

    public Asset fetch(SerialNumber serialNumber)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.SerialNumber == serialNumber.Value
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public Asset fetch(Barcode barcode)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Barcode == barcode.Value
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public ICollection<Asset> fetch(Hostname hostname)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Hostname == hostname.Value && a.IsDeployed == true
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public Asset fetchActive(Hostname hostname)
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Hostname == hostname.Value
                                  select a;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

### Design 3

In the spirit of "tell, don't ask", my last design moves the actual queries to the SerialNumber, Hostname, and Barcode classes instead of asking them for their values. The SerialNumber, etc. classes must now contain a reference to the data source. These would probably benefit from being interfaces so they can support different data sources. I don't know if this is a good design, because they each have a separate reference to the entities. Clients must construct the objects (SerialNumber, etc.) before they send them to the repository. Since clients will not have a reference to the entities, the same reference to the entities can't be injected during construction:

```
// Same interface as last
public interface IAssetRepository
{
    public Asset fetch(SerialNumber serialNumber);
    public Asset fetch(Barcode barcode);
    public ICollection<Asset> fetch(Hostname hostname);
    public Asset fetchActive(Hostname hostname);
}

// Could include other methods like, findStartingWith(), findContains(), etc.
public class SerialNumber
{
    private InventoryEntites entities;
    private String value;

    public SerialNumber(String value)
    { 
        this.value = value;
        this.entities = new InventoryEntities();
    }

    public Asset find()
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.SerialNumber == this.value
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

// Barcode classes is similar to SerialNumber

public class Hostname
{
    private InventoryEntites entities;
    private String value;

    public Hostname(String value)
    { 
        this.value = value;
        this.entities = new InventoryEntities();
    }

    public ICollection<Asset> find()
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Hostname == this.value
                                  select a;

        return query.ToList();
    }

    public Asset findActive()
    {
        IQueryable<Asset> query = from a in this.entities.Assets
                                  where a.Hostname == this.value && a.IsDeployed == true
                                  select a;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public class AssetRepository : IAssetRepository
{
    private InventoryEntites entities;

    public Asset fetch(SerialNumber serialNumber)
    {
        return serialNumber.find();
    }

    public Asset fetch(Barcode barcode)
    {
        return barcode.find();
    }

    public ICollection<Asset> fetch(Hostname hostname)
    {
        return hostname.find();
    }

    public Asset fetchActive(Hostname hostname)
    {
        return hostname.findActive();
    }

    // Other methods could include

    public ICollection<Asset> fetch(Location location)
    {
        return location.find();
    }

    public ICollection<Asset> fetchActive(Location location)
    {
        return location.findActive();
    }
}
```

### Update

Doing some research and found this article:

[MSDN: Patterns in Practice: Cohesion And Coupling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc947917.aspx)

This quote made me think of Design 3. Perhaps this small group of classes should be pulled together into a design more like Design 2?

> **Shotgun Surgery** A certain type of change in the system repeatedly
>   leads to making lots of small changes to a group of classes. Shotgun
>   surgery generally implies that a single logical idea or function is
>   spread out over multiple classes. Try to fix this by pulling all the
>   parts of the code that have to change together into a single cohesive
>   class.

Comment: Without some form of IoC, maintaining contexts across every entity for the sake of having helper methods directly off the object will be painstaking. To me, the model should be POCO, and stick with the repository pattern and keep the data together. How you chose to query that information (with explicit methods or method overloads) is really up to you, but I'd prefer `getX` over 4 `get` methods personally.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Would you mind elaborating on why you prefer `getX` over overloaded `get` methods?

Comment: Because `getX` is more explicit what the method is doing, IMHO. Seeing `ObjectA get(ObjectB obj)` makes me almost question what the method does, where as `ObjectA getByObjectB(ObjectB obj)` assures me that it's using the parameter as a filter. Having worked with WCF and not always having comments to rely on, the [slight] additional work is worth it when it comes down to readability later.

Answer (score 0):

I always use design #1 since it's easier to tell what the repository does. It do communicate the intent.

If you in design two do some kind of validation on the entites (`Barcode` etc) to validate the ID than I would prefer that. If you don't, it doesn't add any value since you could take a `hostName` id and create a `BarCode` with it.

Design three is more of Data Access Objects mixed with repositories. It's a no no.

*(sidenote: Please follow the .NET naming conventions. Method names should be `PascalCase`)*